# Detecting top parent category fails on home page

Tags: categories, loop, query, child-pages

I have the following method to detect a top level category. But it fails on home page returning alway true.

```
//detect parent category
function in_parent_category($cats,$_post=null){
    foreach ((array) $cats as $cat) {
        $descendants = get_term_children((int) $cat, "category");
        if($descendants && in_category($descendants,$_post))
        return true;       
    }
    return false;
}
```

and then in template

```
<?php
    if(in_parent_category(129)){
        echo 'parent';
    } else {
        echo 'not parent';
    }
?>
```

Does anyone knwo to filter home page as well?

**UPDATE**

By filtering I mean that for some reason using the code above it will always return  TRUE if I am on the home page like if the home page is under the top level parent width 129

Comment: You say it's to detect a top level category, but the function `in_parent_category` doesn't do quite that; it checks if the current post is in a child category of a specified parent. Is that definitely what you're after?

Comment: And what do you mean by "filter home page"? You are not using any filters in that code.

Comment: where exactly in the home page template are you using the code?

Comment: @Michael I am checking the post forms part of the top level parent. For example categories: Parent > child 1 > child 2 So the code above lets me find if the post is under PARENT no matter of the deth level. For some reason if I am on the home page it will always think that the parent exists.

Comment: are you using the code within the loop?

Comment: @Michael no, I use it inside the header

Comment: I used the following solution: <?php if(!in_parent_category('1') || is_home()){?>